# C# service crashes on uninstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, windows-installer, uninstallation

I've been working to update a C# service with a new Visual Studio 10 Installer. The old installer is a batch based installer that is a pain to use with Windows 7 and higher, but still works correctly (for both install and uninstall).

I created the new Visual Studio Installation project using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021075) as my guide.

The solution includes a small application used to show the service status in the tray. It's output is added to the installation project and included in all of the custom actions alongside the service.

The service installs and runs correctly with my new installer, but uninstall causes a happy little blue screen of death. The dump shows the crash is coming from ntoskrnl.exe+22fa3 (Critical_Object_Termination).

What methods can be used to track down a crash that occurs during uninstall?

Comment: What happens if you type net stop servicename?  Do you still get a BSOD?

Comment: The service stops successfully. I can start and stop the service without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service can be stopped, then there is something really aweful in your custom action.  Custom actions shouldn't be needed in the first place so try [this](http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html) tutorial instead.

Comment: Removing the custom actions has indeed stopped the crash; of course it also prevents the service from being registered\unregistered, but I may be able to do that manually. I will not be able to use a third party initialization module like ISWIX, but I might be able to do a default merge module.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: ISWIX merely assists in authoring WiX merge modules.  WiX builds them.  The real point of the video was to show how to express a service in a merge module and use it in an MSI.  If you understood that part then you don't really need ISWIX. :)

Comment: I've found and fixed the underlying issue.  Chris was right, there was something awful in the custom action code and I incorrectly assumed it was fully implemented. I am going to leave the issue open for a while to see if someone has any input on the question: what methods can be used to track problems that occur during an uninstall. For example, is it even possible to use Visual Studio debug to "Attach to Process" on the windows installer?

Comment: The fact that the custom action exists to create/remote/start/stop the service in the first place is all wrong.  This is native Windows Installer functionality and if you use it you automatically get verbose logging, declarative and transactional installations for "free".

Comment: Where would this verbose logging be found?  I wasn't seeing anything in the event log and the dump didn't even reference my service.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Aha! I bet that would provide exactly the sort of information I was looking for.  Thank you for all of your assistance.