# Error in executing *.msi file created using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have created a window service using c# in visual studio 2013.
Windows service is working fine.

When i create a setup project and run the .msi file in different computer it gives me an error

[image: Error]

Steps I did :

1.Right click on solution -> Other Project Types ->Visual Studio Installer - Setup Project

2.After adding the name File system Editor -> Select Application Folder -> Right click -> Add -> Project output -> Add Project Output Group pop up
  Project  : selected my project  with Primary Output

[image: File system editor]

3. Select Custom Action Editor -> Install -> Right CLick -> Add Custom Action -> Select the Application folder and the Project output.

Repeated the same for Uninstall

[image: Custom Actions Editor]

4. Build the Installer.

.msi and setup.exe file is created in the folder.

I saw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2aFNtcZfk tutorial to do this.

Can any tell me how to solve this.

Thanks

---

Edit : I have projectInstaller in my Project

```
namespace certify4byd_ver2._0
{
partial class ProjectInstaller
{

    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }


    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;

        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "Quick Source specific development to allow ftp files to be send to ByDesign envir" +
"onment";
        this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "Quick Source Certify4ByDesign";
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "qs_certify4byd_v2.0";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        this.serviceInstaller1.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall);
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }

    #endregion

    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021075/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-net-windows-service-using-visual-studio - anything that you have been missing maybe?

Comment: @DirkVollmar : No i have not missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you've copied your application's files to the target machine and that's it. If you're writing a Windows Service there are other steps that you have to take to get an MSI package to install it as a service.

Does your project have the `ServiceInstaller` class somewhere? That's how .NET wants you to install services.

A Visual Studio Installer project is probably not the best way to go, at least in my experience. Have a look at [Debuggable Installable Service](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/01/c-toolbox-debug-able-self-installable-windows-service-template-redux.aspx), an extension for Visual Studio that allows you to create self-installing Windows Services (with a command line argument) that are also console debuggable out of the box. It's been a lifesaver for me when writing services because you're not messing around with `ServiceInstaller` and everything is done for you.

My other suggestion is, on top of using Debuggable Installable Service, have a look at [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/). It needs to be installed everywhere you plan on developing your products (a bit of a pain if you're developing under source control), but it also allows you to install services and gives you more fine-grained control of how your applications will be installed.

I don't recommend a Visual Studio Installer project.

Comment: I have Service Installer in my Project. Please see the Edited area.
Thanks for advicing another tool. I have used in VS installer project in Past. I think i have missed something, which i cannot verify.