# How to create an installer for a python based windows service

Tags: python, windows-services

By following this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)

I have successfully created a windows service in python and installed on my device and it is doing its job accurately.
Now My question is that how can I deploy this service on some other pc definitely we have to make an installer for that like we do for c# based windows service as it is explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021075/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-net-windows-service-using-visual-studio).

Is there any way to make an installer for python based windows service and we give that .msi file to someone and he download it in his pc.
I am a newbie in stack overflow if I breached any rule or regulation of this site while asking this question kindly forgive and correct me help me to solve my this task Thank you.

Comment: have you tried https://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/ or https://www.advancedinstaller.com/create-msi-python-executable.html

Comment: @Kristian but unfortunately it didn't work for me.