# Visual Studio MSI Installer With Properties Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have **Windows Service** C# project. I'm trying to create MSI installer for my **Windows Service** project and I'd like this installer to ask:

- **Database connection string**
- **Port Number**

During installation process.

I'd like installation process to collect those values and set them to the configuration file of installed **Windows Service**.

Can you please guide me to anything that describes how to create MSI installer in visual studio that will ask me to set this properties during installation and sets those properties to the config file of installed service.

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to the following two links: [Creating a Windows Service and Installer using .net and WiX](https://cmartcoding.com/creating-a-windows-service-and-installer-using-net-and-wix/). [How to create an installer for a .net Windows Service using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021075/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-net-windows-service-using-visual-studio).